# retrieve the duration of each of my youtube videos using C# .NET and the YouTube Data API v3

Tags: c#, .net, video, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to get the duration of each of my YouTube videos using C# .NET and the YouTube Data API v3 (NOT JavaScript or any other client side language)?

I've been searching for days and the only thing I've come up with is the example that Google has on their [.NET Code Samples page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet) which only shows how to get a playlistItems.list. However, this does not give me a list of videos with their associated durations from the contentDeatils.

Please help me figure this out.
Thank you all.

Comment: It looks like you can do it by fetching the [videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) and checking the `contentDetails.duration` property.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @adrianbanks, but the only way I've been able to come close to grabbing the video object is to grab the playlist.item object which does not contain the duration property. Is there any code example that you could point me to that shows how to grab the actual video object using C# .Net?

Comment: Did you use the *Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 Client Library*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have been in similar situation where I needed to update descriptions of all my uploads. See hidden gem here: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/dotnet

In project `Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples.UpdateVideos` you will find a loop which you can slightly modify and use to get duration for each video.

```
foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
{
    var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;

    Console.WriteLine("Videos in list {0}", uploadsListId);

    var nextPageToken = "";
    while (nextPageToken != null)
    {
        var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
        playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
        playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
        playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

        // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
        var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
        {
            var videoRequest = youtubeService.Videos.List("snippet");
            videoRequest.Id = playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId;
            videoRequest.MaxResults = 1;
            var videoItemRequestResponse = await videoRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            // Get the videoID of the first video in the list
            var video = videoItemRequestResponse.Items[0];
            var duration = video.ContentDetails.Duration;
        }

        nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Janis. While working on it I did come up with a similar solution. However, I noticed a performance issue. I have 22 videos to access and using this technique, I was making 23 calls to the YouTube API (one to get the playlistItemsListResponse object, and another 22 calls (one for each video inside the last foreach loop). To remedy this, I worked out a two call process. I first call the playlistItemsListRequest to get a collection of the playlists, then I call the videoRequest to get a list of the videos from the playlist which I iterate through to get the durations.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, This is an explanation of how I eventually resolved this issue.

The objective I wish to accomplish with the YouTube data API is to go and retrieve a list of videos from any YouTube channel based on a username or a channel ID.

Ideally, we should just be able to ask YouTube for all the videos from a specific YouTube channel. However, it doesn't seem to work that way.
Ultimately, we need to send a video list request to the YouTubeService.Videos.List method. This will allow us to retrieve the content details, snippet, and statistics for a list of video objects. This method, however, requires a couple of parameters. One is the VideoListRequest.ID parameter which is a string array of the video IDs in the collection of videos you wish to retrieve. The other is the VideoListRequest.MaxResults parameter. This will be the maximum number of videos you wish to pull back.

To retrieve a list of video IDs we need to make another call to the YouTube API and retrieve a list of playlist items from the YouTubeService.PlaylistItems.List method. This method, however, requires the UploadsListID which must be acquired through yet another call to the YouTube API’s YouTubeService.Channels.List method.

So, it turns out we need to make 3 calls to the YouTube API as shown in the chart below.

Step One is to get a list of channels based on either a username or a channel ID. The UploadsListId will come from the ChannelListResponse: channelsListResponse.Items[0].ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads.

Step Two is to get a list of playlist items using the UploadsListID from the previous step. This allows us to retrieve the video ID for each of the videos in the uploaded videos playlist and place them into a string list.

Finally, Step Three is to get the list of videos based on the video IDs in the previous string list. With this response, we can retrieve the duration in each video and convert YouTube's HMS format to a "usable" Timespan formatted string (h:mm:ss).

[image: YouTube API Process Chart]

This is the code I used to accomplish the above description:

```
    public async Task<List<Video>> GetVideoListAsync(ChannelListMethod Method, string MethodValue, int? MaxVideos)
    {
        // Define variables needed for this method
        List<string> videoIdList = new List<string>();
        List<Video> videoList = new List<Video>();
        string uploadsListId = null;

        // Make sure values passed into the method are not null or empty.
        if (MaxVideos == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(MaxVideos));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MethodValue))
        {
            return videoList;
        }

        // Create the service.
        using (YouTubeService youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            ApiKey = _apiKey,
            ApplicationName = _appName
        }))
        {
            // Step ONE is to get a list of channels for a specified YouTube user or ChannelID.
            // Create the FIRST Request object to get a list of YouTube Channels and get their contentDetails
            // based on either ForUserName or ChannelID.
            ChannelsResource.ListRequest channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
            if (Method == ChannelListMethod.ForUserName)
            {
                // Build the ChannelListRequest using UserName
                channelsListRequest.ForUsername = MethodValue;
            }
            else
            {
                // Build the ChannelListRequest using ChannelID
                channelsListRequest.Id = MethodValue;
            }

            // This is the FIRST Request to the YouTube API.
            // Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource to get a list of channel IDs.
            // We are only interested in the Uploads playlist of the first channel.
            try
            {
                ChannelListResponse channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
                uploadsListId = channelsListResponse.Items[0].ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorException = ex;
                return videoList;
            }

            // Step TWO is to get a list of playlist items from the Uploads playlist.
            // From the API response, use the Uploads playlist ID (uploadsListId) to be used to get list of videos
            // from the videos uploaded to the user's channel.
            string nextPageToken = "";
            while (nextPageToken != null)
            {
                // Create the SECOND Request object for requestring a list of Playlist items
                // from the channel's Uploads playlist.
                // Limit the list to maxVideos items and continue to iterate through the pages.
                PlaylistItemsResource.ListRequest playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("contentDetails");
                playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = MaxVideos;
                playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

                // This is the SECOND Request to YouTube and get a Response object containing
                // the playlist items in the channel's Uploads playlist.
                // Then iterate through the Response items to build a string list of the video IDs
                try
                {
                    PlaylistItemListResponse playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
                    foreach (PlaylistItem playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
                    {
                        videoIdList.Add(playlistItem.ContentDetails.VideoId.ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrorException = ex;
                    return videoList;
                }

                // Now that we have a collection (string array) of video IDs,
                // Step THREE is to retrieve the snippet, contentDetails, and statistics parts of the 
                // list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                try
                {
                    // Create the THIRD Request object for requestring a list of videos and their associated metadata.
                    var VideoListRequest = youtubeService.Videos.List("snippet, contentDetails, statistics");
                    // The next line converts the list of video Ids to a comma seperated string array of the video IDs
                    VideoListRequest.Id = String.Join(",", videoIdList);
                    VideoListRequest.MaxResults = MaxVideos;

                    var VideoListResponse = await VideoListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                    // This is the THIRD Request to the YouTube API to get a Response object
                    // containing Collect each Video duration and convert to a usable time format.
                    foreach (var video in VideoListResponse.Items)
                    {
                        video.ContentDetails.Duration = HMSToTimeSpan(video.ContentDetails.Duration).ToString();
                        videoList.Add(video);
                    }

                    // request next page
                    nextPageToken = VideoListResponse.NextPageToken;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrorException = ex;
                    return videoList;
                }
            }
            return videoList;
        }
    }
```

I know this isn't the perfect solution, or perhaps the "best" one, but I hope this helps others with the same issue.

Thanks for all of your help @Janis S